# Segue show(push) not appearing on Objective C project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode9.2

I'm trying to create a native navigation but in [Apple developer guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/ImplementNavigation.html) says that I have to use show(push) for segue but in my project I only have 3 options

[image]

and in the segue documentation says that this 3 options are deprecated. I do not know if I need to upgrade something or I keep going with deprecated segues. I start this project a year ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using an old-style storyboard. Select any view controller in the storyboard, switch to the File inspector on the right, and check Use Auto Layout and Use Trait Variations. The modern versions of the segues will magically spring to life.